# Simple (I hope) BoltForms questions

Tags: bolt-cms

- How can I change the text on a submit button?
- I vaguely remember the option that it is possible to direct users to a page after submission. Is that documented?

Answer (score 1):

The submit button just behaves like any Symfony Forms field, so you can simply to this:

```
submit:
  type: submit
  options:
    label: My Button Text
```

As for redirect, sort of. You can't redirect yet, but you *can* give different HTML.

```
{% set html_pre = '<h1>This will appear above the un-submitted form</h1>' %}
{% set html_post = '<p>Thank you for submitting your form<p>' %}
{{ boltforms('formname', html_pre, html_post) }}
```

Comment: Submit text: Thanks! I overlooked the options line.

Comment: As for the URL, it's mainly because I often put forms in the footer and would like to prevent the browser from scrolling to the top after submitting, which pushes the notification out of the viewport. I've solved this (in SimpleForms) with a front-end hack before, but it feels awkward to do that.

Comment: Agreed… I need a day with more hours in it myself. However, Bob & Co are doing some work soon on it, might get into their scope. It's not had to implement, just takes a tiny bit of time to implement.